# Images auto deleted after exactly nine months... or my visit triggered some kind of heart attack?

Tags: images, troubleshooting

So I looked at my [website](https://vache.au) and noticed that some of the images had disappeared. It was fine yesterday. The images that were deleted were from when I first set it up (so the files in the media library were my favicon, my avatar (for Simple Local Avatars) and a picture in my first post. All of those I uploaded September 26, last year.

I can't see if it happens again soon because I'm lazy and my next post was nearly a month later :/

I'm just finding it hard to believe it's a coincidence that it happened after **exactly** nine months. And just after I wrote that, I checked my server logs (sensitive data hidden)

```
2023-06-25 19:16:33.269293 [INFO] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23295-H3:F694B1998CD77579-4#APVH_www.vache.au:443] Abort request processing by PID:35131, kill: 0, begin time: 5, sent time: 5, req processed: 1
2023-06-25 19:16:40.796439 [INFO] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23295-H3:F694B1998CD77579-8#APVH_www.vache.au:443] Abort request processing by PID:35187, kill: 0, begin time: 7, sent time: 7, req processed: 0
2023-06-25 22:16:35.391635 [INFO] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23109-H3:6A0479FD842D6FF6-308#APVH_www.vache.au:443] Abort request processing by PID:18476, kill: 0, begin time: 0, sent time: 0, req processed: 0
2023-06-25 22:16:35.392600 [INFO] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23109-H3:6A0479FD842D6FF6-304#APVH_www.vache.au:443] Abort request processing by PID:18475, kill: 0, begin time: 0, sent time: 0, req processed: 0
2023-06-25 22:16:35.393444 [INFO] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23109-H3:6A0479FD842D6FF6-312#APVH_www.vache.au:443] Abort request processing by PID:18477, kill: 0, begin time: 0, sent time: 0, req processed: 0
2023-06-25 22:16:39.971031 [NOTICE] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23109-H3:6A0479FD842D6FF6-320#APVH_www.vache.au:443] [STDERR] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "title" on null in (file path on server)/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php on line 905\n
2023-06-25 22:20:43.869638 [INFO] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23303-H3:727DBF0CC1A14563-96#APVH_www.vache.au:443] Abort request processing by PID:22381, kill: 0, begin time: 0, sent time: 0, req processed: 3
2023-06-25 22:27:30.077211 [NOTICE] [12124] [T0] [(my home IP address):23460-H3:6EDE8BC8D74F2EE7-0#APVH_www.vache.au:443] [STDERR] PHP Warning:  An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server&#8217;s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/forums/">support forums</a>. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in (file path on server)/public_html/wp-admin/includes/translation-install.php on line 68\n
```

I'm not sure what time zone the server's logs are in but it's possible my visit triggered WordPress to have some kind of weird heart attack but to my untrained eye nothing there looks like deleting images (or why it's only the older files).

I have another WordPress installation for another domain on the same server and it was completely unaffected, and it has older images (I just visited to check).

I've looked through all the settings in the server's control panel and nothing seems to explain why this would happen. I also looked and there is a `/public_html/wp_content/uploads/2022/09/` folder, but it's empty.

I suppose y'all probably want some technical data. I'm not sure how much is relevant, so feel free to ask for more.

- WordPress version: 6.2.2 (automatically updates)

  - PHP version 8.1.17
- Theme: A child of Twenty Twenty Two *(custom, my own spin on it, but not really changing anything other than cosmetics)*
- Plugins enabled (all auto-updating):

  - Advanced Editor Tools
  - Layout Grid
  - Phoenix Media Rename
  - Simple Lightbox
  - Simple Local Avatars
  - WordPress.org Glossary *(I should probably uninstall that, I'm not using it in the slightest)*
  - WP Super Cache
  - *(I installed WP Crontrol after this to see if there were any cron jobs that might have done it, but couldn't see anything that looked suss)*

Anyone got any ideas what happened? I'm beat.

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd strongly recommend reaching out to your hosting company's support team. It's hard to guess what might have happened here, but they'll be better positioned to help you with this than we will.